# Dynamically add entry control in Xamarin

Tags: c#, json, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to fetch the **XML Entry Control** from **API**, available in **JSON**.

All the attributes for Entry control are in JSON. I want to add them in `.xml` page and get their values (when user enter in app) in `ViewModel` (through data binding).

**UPDATE**

Update the Code according to the answer.

```
public partial class FormPage : ContentPage, IRootView
{
    public List<Form> forms { get; set; }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public Datum[] data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public Form[] form { get; set; }
    }

    public class Form
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int max_length { get; set; }
        public bool required { get; set; }
    }

    public FormPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var json = @{};

        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

        forms = new List<Form>();
        forms = list.data.FirstOrDefault().form.ToList();

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is nice to hear what you want to do, but what is your explicit question? What did you try so far to reach your goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Deserialize Json:** Install `Newtonsoft.Json` from NuGet.

Convert the json to classes and then get the list of the json data.

In your VS, Edit> Paste Special> Paste JSON As Classes

```
 public class Rootobject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Datum[] data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public Form[] form { get; set; }
}

public class Form
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int max_length { get; set; }
    public bool required { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize to get the list:

```
   var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

**Use the Bindablelayout.ItemTemplate of StackLayout to setup the template of Entry:**

Xaml:

```
 <StackLayout x:Name="DynamicEntry" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding forms}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Entry Placeholder="{Binding label}" MaxLength="{Binding max_length}" />

            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
 public List<Form> forms { get; set; }
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var json = @"{
'success': 'true',
'data': [
    {
        'form': [
            {
                'label': 'Name',
                'name': 'name',
                'type': 'text',
                'max_length': '15',
                'required': 'true'
            },
            {
                'label': 'Email',
                'name': 'email',
                'type': 'email',
                'max_length': '30',
                'required': 'true'
            }
        ]
    }
]
}";
        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);

        forms = new List<Form>();
        forms = list.data.FirstOrDefault().form.ToList();

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
```

[image]

Please note if you want to set the Kayboard with different types, you need convert the list with Keyboard class.

Comment: thanks for response, but one thing, why are u using `var json`.. I want to get this "json" response from server (it's dynamic)

Comment: I do not have the server to get the `json` response. So i use json string directly for reference.

Comment: lol.. really sorry.. and yes, for now, I used ur code and compile it and i'm getting this error `Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: 'An exception was thrown while activating Mobile.App.Views.Form.FormPage.'`

Comment: Which line of the code throw the error? Make the breakpoint to debug step by step.

Comment: i added the breakpoint on every line and when page is opened and `InitializeComponent();` is called, it return this error..

Comment: When you test only the code i provided, do you get the same error?

Comment: Create the contentpage with xaml, and add the code into code behind of contentpage. Do not forget to add the class of `Rootobject`.

Comment: Check the forms first to make sure you get the list. And then check the binding in code behind (`this.BindingContext = this;`) and Xaml (`BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding forms}"`).