# Bind Data from Bindablelayout.ItemTemplate in ViewModel in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I had an Issue in [Dynamically adding Entry Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67481442/14515147), which [Wendy Zang - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11850033/wendy-zang-msft) helped and solved it.

The code to Get the list of entries from API is written in `.xml.cs` page, and in `.xml` page, the **Bindablelayout.ItemTemplate of StackLayout** is being used to **setup the template of Entry**.

It's working perfectly, but the Code to Submit the Form is written in `ViewModel`.

When I paste the code of `.xml.cs` page in `ViewModel`, I can't get the Entries and when the code is in `xml.cs` for which I have to set the `this.BindingContext = this;` code in the `ViewModel` isn't executing.

**.xml**

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding forms}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Entry Name="{Binding name}" Placeholder="{Binding label}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

**xml.cs**

```
RootObject list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(fields);

forms = new List<Form>();
forms = list.data.FirstOrDefault().Form.ToList();

this.BindingContext = this;
```

**Button in XAML & ViewModel**

```
<Button
x:Name="SubmitButton"
Text="Submit"
Command="{Binding FormCommand}">
```

```
public ICommand FormCommand=> new Command(async (x) => await FormButton(default, default));
```

**UPDATE**

Code to fetch the dynamic fields from server.

```
public async Task CreateCollection()
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://example.com/entry"));

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());

    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
    string entries = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    RootObject list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(entries);

    form = new List<Form>();
    form = list.data.FirstOrDefault().form.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `<ContentPage.Content>` in your xaml file? If so, should be `this.Content.BindingContent = this;`

Comment: @Shaw thanks for response, I used this and still can't submit form in `ViewModel` (I posted the sample of Button code from `.xml` page and `ViewModel`).. if there isn't `this.Content.BindingContent = this;` in `xml.cs`, then it's clickable else, it's not

Comment: if I paste the `xml.cs` code (to get the entries from api) in `ViewModel`, can't view entries..

Comment: Remove "x", make it `async () => `. And if list binding is fine, keep using the previous binding code.

Comment: @Shaw I tried Wendy's solution and When app is in debug mode, and I refresh the `.xml ` page, Form appears, else it don't appears on first time when page appears.. any idea why it's behaving like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For complete understanding, have a look at [@Wendy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11850033/wendy-zang-msft) solution. The problem was that, Form wasn't appearing when Page opens up, but when I was in Debug Mode, and refresh the `.xml` page, it appears.

[@Shaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10366303/shaw) recommend to use `ObservableCollection<>` instead of `List<>`, but on `list.data.FirstOrDefault().form.ToList();` it said *cannot convert 'System.Collection.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<>'*.

I fixed it.. here is the complete solution.

```
private ObservableCollection<Form> _forms = new ObservableCollection<Form>();
public ObservableCollection<Form> Forms
{
    get
    {
        return _forms;
    }
    set
    {
        this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _forms, value);
    }
}
```

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);

foreach (var i in list.data.Where(c => c.id == ""))
{
    _forms.Add(i.form.ToList());
}
```

Comment: If `form = list.data.FirstOrDefault().form.ToList();` works previously, you should be able to use `form = new ObservableCollection<Form>(list.data.FirstOrDefault().form);` instead. But I'm not too sure about the type of `list.data.FirstOrDefault().form`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this with ViewModel, you could refer to the code below.

Xaml:

```
      <StackLayout>
        <Button
    x:Name="SubmitButton"
    Text="Submit"
    Command="{Binding FormCommand}"></Button>
        <StackLayout x:Name="DynamicEntry" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding forms}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Entry Placeholder="{Binding label}" MaxLength="{Binding max_length}" />

                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Form> forms { get; set; }
    public ICommand FormCommand { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        CreateCollection();
        FormCommand = new Command(async (x) => await FormButton(default, default));
    }

    private Task FormButton(object p1, object p2)
    {
        return Task.Delay(2000);
    }

    public void CreateCollection()
    {
        var json = @"{
'success': 'true',
'data': [
{
    'form': [
        {
            'label': 'Name',
            'name': 'name',
            'type': 'text',
            'max_length': '15',
            'required': 'true'
        },
        {
            'label': 'Email',
            'name': 'email',
            'type': 'email',
            'max_length': '30',
            'required': 'true'
        }
    ]
}
]
}";
        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);

        forms = new List<Form>();
        forms = list.data.FirstOrDefault().form.ToList();
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I used the static JSON entries, and It's working fine, but when I fetch the entries from api, can't able to get it in the view (while I can get the entries from api).

Comment: but when I write this exact code in `.xml.cs` instead of ViewModel than working fine..

Comment: I posted the code above for how I fetch the dynamic fields from server.

Comment: When app is in debug mode, and I refresh the `.xml` page, **Form appears**.. why is it behaving like this? and how to fix this?

Comment: I made the `CreateCollection()` function, both `void` & `async` and also write the api call/response in `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` & `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`.. and still, it isn't showing Form when Page appears, but when I refresh the `.xml` page (when it's in debug mode, connected with PC), it appears...

Comment: @Stavrogin 1. Try to call the `CreateCollection()` method in `OnAppearing` instead of the constructor. 2. Try to use `ObservableCollection<Form> Forms` instead of list

Comment: Calling `CreateCollection()` method in `OnAppearing` didn't make any difference and I used `ObservableCollection<Form> Forms` but on `list.data.FirstOrDefault().form.ToList();` it says **cannot convert 'System.Collection.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<>'**

Comment: Thanks, with yours help, it get solved. I posted below the complete solution, have a look, and if there is any suggestion, it'll be great.