# Get the Entry Value from Dynaimc Form in ViewModel Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin App, I'm getting [Dynamic Form from Server & add in XML Entry Control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67482978/14515147).

There are multiple Entry and they are dynamic (it could be of any number), as I don't know the number and their names, I can't write **bindable properties in ViewModel** to get the Value of Entry.

Is there any way to get the value of Entry from dynamic form?

**ViewModel**

Code the get the dynamic fields from API

```
Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://example.com/entry"));

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
string entries = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

RootObject list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(entries);

form = new List<Form>();
form = list.data.FirstOrDefault().form.ToList();
```

```
public List<Form> forms { get; set; }
```

Convert the json to classes and then get the list of the json data.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Datum[] data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public Form[] form { get; set; }
}

public class Form
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int max_length { get; set; }
    public bool required { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: why don't you bind the Entry Text property to a property on your `Form` class?

Comment: when they are dynamic (I don't know there names and numbers), how will I get the Text (elsewhere in the app, when I want to get the value input by user in Entry, in Viewmodel, I had to user **Bindable Properties**).. but here how will I do that?

Comment: create a property on your Form class named "Value".  Bind the Text property of the Entry to Value.  Then elsewhere in your code you can get the values by referring to that list

Comment: Imagine a ListView binded to "forms", and display a "name". How would you do that? There will be a `name` property in your `Form` class (the model). And that's the same binding you need for your BindableLayout, no matter a label or an entry inside.

Comment: I posted a small example of "create a property on your Form class named "Value"".. kindly have a look, is this what u want me to do?

Comment: @Jason sorry, i tried but isn't able to achieve it..

Comment: no, all you need to do is create a regular string property on your Form class and bind to it.  You are making this 100x more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: you mean `public string value { get; set; }` inside `public class Form { }` and `<Entry Text="{Binding value}" />` ?

Comment: @Jason I updated a question by adding a code, as I understood from your comments.. `var item in value.ToList()` had a Zero values. can u please have a look.. thanks.. I'm sorry, I don't have much experience in Xamarin, I'm trying.. thanks for helping :)

Comment: This is basic C#.  What is the purpose of `_value = new List<Form>();`?  You should be using the same `List<Form>` that your `ListView` is already bound to.

Comment: okay, I updated the code above, please have a look (what else is wrong in it)? .. and this time when i click on Submit button, the page stuck there..

Comment: @Jason one thing more, I'm using `ObservableCollection` to get & set the Dynamic Form. (above i added the code for it)

Comment: there is no "Submit" button in the code you posted so I have no idea what it does or why it might be stuck.  If you can post a [mcve] somewhere I'll take a quick look at it

Comment: @Jason thanks alot, solved it.. posted a complete code in the answer, have a look, and if there is any suggestion, it'll be kind of u.. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @Jason's comments and suggestions, finally solved it.

Using `ObservableCollection` to get & set the Dynamic Form.

```
private ObservableCollection<Form> _form = new ObservableCollection<Form>();
public ObservableCollection<Form> form
{
    get => _form;
    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _form, value);
}
```

Property on Form class named "Value". Binded the Text property of the Entry to Value.

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Value}" />

public class Form
{
    // Code
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection<Form> Value
{
    get => _form;
    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _form, value);
}
```

Code to get the values by referring to that list

```
foreach (var item in Value.ToList())
{
    item.Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: if `Value` is a string, there is no point in using `ToString()` on it

Comment: removed it, thanks.. one thing, how can I make a check on `Value`, to see if it's empty or not?

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`

Answer (score 1):

You could get all the Entry via `Children` of `StackLayout`. I use the same code from previous thread for referene.

Xaml:

```
 <StackLayout>
    
    <StackLayout x:Name="DynamicEntry" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding forms}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Entry Placeholder="{Binding label}" MaxLength="{Binding max_length}" />

            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
    <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var entries = DynamicEntry.Children;
        foreach (var item in entries)
        {
            var entry = item as Entry;
            var text = entry.Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This *Code behind* section can only be use in `.xml.cs` file, not in ViewModel.

Comment: If you want to get the value from the Entry which the user input and them transfer to viewmodel, you could create a property in viewmodel and then get the value to update. But i do not understand what does the `not in ViewModel` mean?

Comment: that's my entire question, how will i create a property in a viewmodel, while I don't know anything about entry (name or how many are they)?

Comment: @Jason recommend me to "create a property on your Form class named "Value"".. I posted above code in update section, is this what he meant?

Comment: @Stavrogin The way i provided could get all the values of all the Entries. It should be a list. And use `INotifyPropertyChanged` to update.

Comment: If you want to get all the values not for the specific entry value, i would post the code later.

Comment: yes yes.. i want to get the values (user entered text in entry) for each specific entry (all of them)

Comment: one question, I created a bindable property in viewmodel for `DynamicEntry`, what will be it type?

Comment: I am not sure why you create a bindable property in viewmodel for DynamicEntry. For the usage of binable property, you could refer to the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties

Comment: you wrote above in comment **you could create a property in viewmodel and then get the value to update.**.. hey, i'm really sorry, but am very confuse, trying different things but none is working out..

Comment: The update is the property i mean. And make the `Form` class inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged` to update. Check the code in the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: I tried to create a property, I'm not if it's the right way to do, but i followed some blog and `DynamicEntry.Children`, it said, `Childern` isn't found..

Comment: `DynamicEntry` is the name of the `StackLayout` in xaml.