# POST Dynamic Values in Array in multipart/form-data in c#

Tags: c#, .net, rest, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin App, the form is Dynamic, means the Form is been Fetch from API and then I [Get the Entry Value from Dynamic Form in ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67592229/14515147).

Sending data to backend with static values.

```
var fields = "[{\"name\": \"firstName\", \"value\": \"Hannah\"}, {\"name\": \"lastName\", \"value\": \"Arendt\"}, {\"name\": \"email\", \"value\": \"example@mail.com\"}]";

Content.Add(new StringContent(fields), "fields");
```

Now, as I'm getting Form dynamically.

```cs
foreach (var item in Value.ToList())
{
    item.name;
    item.Value;
}
```

Just want to replace `name` and `value` with dynamic data (`item.name` and `item.Value`).

```
var fields = [{"name": item.name, "value": item.Value}];

Content.Add(new StringContent(fields), "fields");
```

Comment: The multipart is a Mime attachment to the body of the HTML response and starts with a new line that begins with two dashes.   See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)

Comment: do you control the server?  Is there any reason that you need to submit the data this way?

Comment: do I control the server? no.. it is requirement by backend developers

Comment: there are many existing questions about using MultiPart - have you reviewed them?

Comment: Yes, actually I successfully sent data to backend with static values, I just want to send now with dynamic data.

Comment: I posted above an updated code.. kindly, have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will be useful.

you need to add: `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

```
var values = Value.ToList().Select(item => new { item.name, item.value }).ToList();

var fields = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
```